# table-column is not wrapping text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Screenshot**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76530061@N04/6871006190/in/photostream)

**Important Note :** This application does not support Internet Explorer. I will be happy with solution which will work in Chrome and Firefox.

I am using dynamic code (velocity-spring) for generating an html-table. **Number of columns are not fixed** (so I cannot specify width for headings). The second column values are always a link. Structure like this :

```
<table>
<tr>    
    <th ALIGN=CENTER> heading 1 </th>
    <th ALIGN=CENTER> heading 2 </th>
    ... ... .... .. .. .. 
    <th ALIGN=CENTER> heading n </th>
</tr>
<tr ALIGN=CENTER>    
    <td ALIGN=CENTER> value 1 </td>
    <td ALIGN=CENTER> <a href="mypage.html">value 2</a> </td> <!-- this column is a link -->
    ... ... .... .. .. .. 
    <td ALIGN=CENTER> value n </td>
</tr>
.... now more rows followed
</table>
```

Now problem is that if the second column (with hyperlink) contains a "loooooooooooooooooooooooong" value (without spaces) the other columns are wrapping their text. Please help me with css/jQuery/Javascript code, so that I maintain the structure of table with whatever values come from back-end.

UPDATE:

After getting answer, I updated my table code like below (as they say specify `width` and use `word-break`) :

```
<table>
<tr>    
    <th ALIGN=CENTER> heading 1 </th>
    <th style="word-wrap:break-word; width: 200px;" ALIGN=CENTER> heading 2 </th>
    ... ... .... .. .. .. 
    <th ALIGN=CENTER> heading n </th>
</tr>
<tr ALIGN=CENTER>    
    <td ALIGN=CENTER> value 1 </td>
    <td ALIGN=CENTER style="word-wrap:break-word; width: 200px;"> <a href="mypage.html">value 2</a> </td> <!-- this column is a link -->
    ... ... .... .. .. .. 
    <td ALIGN=CENTER> value n </td>
</tr>
.... now more rows followed
</table>
```

I know I need to accept and vote up usefull answers, doing. But please help me. I cant send you live URL. Attaching screen shots very soon.

[**Screenshot**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76530061@N04/6871006190/in/photostream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word-wrap` will work but you need to specify a `width` for the column.

Comment: please give me some more ways, I have updated the post. I would be thankful to you always. voting up

Comment: i have added screenshot now, can you have a look at this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the CSS attribute "word-wrap."

```
table td a
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is supported [in all major browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and should fix your problem.

You can see a [test case I created here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/B3mhq/). You don't need to specify a width for the element, it will work without (resize the result window to see.)

Comment: In your example the `width` is not required because you use a `p` which is a block element unless otherwise styled. The qestion refers to a specific column inside a table.

Comment: please give me some more ways, I have updated the post. I would be thankful to you always. voting up

Comment: i have added screenshot now, can you have a look at this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
table td a {
    // set a width
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

The 'word-wrap' solution only works in IE and browsers supporting CSS3.

The best cross browser solution is to use script language (javascript or whatever) to locate long strings and place inside them in regular intervals the html entity #8203; This entity breaks the long words nicely, and works on all browsers.

A nice regular expression should be:

```
 "everyverylongword".replace(/([^\s-]{5})([^\s-]{5})/,"$1&shy;$2")
```

Comment: trying this. will let you know the result. I will vote you up once I get the privilege.